# Bootstrap jQuery dynamic table edit/delete/view button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-table, dynamic-tables

I'd appreciate any help on this. I have this DataTable with the last column being a button that spans various options such as Edit/Delete/View. Upon clicking that, it should delete the entire row. However, I'm not able to get the currently clicked element.
Here's my code

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
        console.log($(this).data('value'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <span class="dropdown">
                                                <button id="btnSearchDrop_{{ index }}" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                        aria-expanded="true"
                                                        class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-right"><i
                                                        class="ft-settings"></i></button>
                                                <span id='selected' aria-labelledby=btnSearchDrop_{{ index }}" class="dropdown-menu mt-1 dropdown-menu-right">
                                                  <a href="#" data-value="edit_{{ row.DealKey }}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ft-edit-2"></i> Edit</a>
                                                  <a href="#" data-value="delete_{{ row.DealKey }}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ft-trash-2"></i> Delete</a>
                                                  <a href="#" data-value="view_{{ row.DealKey }}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="ft-plus-circle primary"></i> View</a>
                                                </span>
  </span>
</td>
```

This should log the id of  tag but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of jquery you are using but [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function works in versions 1.4.3 and above. I tested your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wLqve61r/) with jquery-3.3.1, which worked fine. Another way to get what you want would be to use `.attr()` function instead of `.data()` like:

```
alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
```

Comment: Okay. so what's happening is once I start from first row and click edit, the console logs the id of first row. Then I go to the second row and click edit, the console properly logs id of second row. Now, when I go to the first row again, the console still logs the id of the second row. Someone it doesn't reset itself. Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: can you check here, see if the issue happens here as well ? https://jsfiddle.net/wLqve61r/3/

Comment: here, its working fine. You think something may be wrong with CSS?

Comment: Umm, not sure, maybe, but don't think so. Can you create a fiddle with css too ?